# SQL statement unique ID and then grouping by unique ID and counting a distinct other ID group

Tags: sql

I want to make a query that makes the unique ID concatenate and then group by this unique ID and then count another field by distinct. I get the output but the count is off. I verified through another source.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(x, y, z, a) AS 'uniqueid',
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS 'count'
FROM bv
GROUP BY
    x, y, z, a
```

Comment: What is the sql that was used to verify through another source?   Please show the other source's sql. What is the timing of these two counts?? same instant?? or some time lag?   Are all counts higher/mixed/lower?  Please share some data, and above count and another source count...!!

Comment: The other source being used is tableau unfortunately I can't share the data. Tableau makes the calculated field similar to the concatenate and then counts the id file and gives me 8k more records compared to the SQL query. The id number can be used several times that's why we want to count by Id. At the end we want to filter it by distinct id = 1

Comment: I simply don't understand what count is off.  Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: It seems that 'uniqueid'  and  'id'  are separate columns.  Yet they (probably) have different values.  And Tableau has a "SIMILAR Field"  yet not exactly the same field? If different from concatenate, no wonder different results are being gotten?  Also, does tableau count(id)  or  count(distinct id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group on the same non-aggregated fields (or composite fields in this case) as you have in your `SELECT` list. You should be able to use the query below to get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(x,y,z,a) AS 'uniqueid' 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS 'count'
FROM bv
GROUP BY CONCAT(x,y,z,a)
```